# How to group rows using more than 1 key when there is no consistent 1:1 mapping between keys?

Tags: r, group-by

| uniqid | client_id | hh_id | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| u1 | c1 | h1 | 1 |
| u1 | c2 | h1 | 1 |
| u1 | c3 | h2 | 1 |
| u2 | c4 | h1 | 1 |
| u2 | c5 | h2 | 1 |
| u3 | c6 | h3 | 2 |
| u3 | c7 | h3 | 2 |
| u3 | c8 | h4 | 2 |

Let's say a Household can have more than 1 individual as a part of it, with each of them having one master unique-id in the system. But each individual can have more than 1 client-id generated in the system due to the process/workflow. Also there are rare cases where the same client is mapped to more than 1 household.

Expected outcome is to group all the related individuals together into one group, say g1, such that all the individuals who are part of a household (or overlapping with other households), are there in one place.

Dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(list(uniqid = c("u1", "u1", "u1", "u2", "u2", "u3", "u3", "u3"), 
                  client_id = c("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", "c7", "c8"), 
                  hh_id = c("h1", "h1", "h2", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h3", "h4"), 
                  group_id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2)))
```

Group_id is the expected output, one unique id per group of related individuals (or household).

I have tried this approach to group the individuals, solving part of the problem, but this would miss out other household-ids the individual is mapped to.

```
df %>% group_by(hh_id) %>% 
  arrange(hh_id, uniqid) %>% 
  mutate(hh_group = str_c(uniqid, collapse = ""))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  And can you post your data in a reusable format:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Please do not add tags to your post that are not relevant to your question.

Comment: @Ben copy the table and use ``clipr::read_clip_tbl()``

Comment: @user438383 Yes correct.

Comment: can you include the table that has the expected output in your question

Comment: @KU99 Data is added in reusable format now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a graph relation. Use the following:

```
library(igraph)
df$groups <-components(graph_from_data_frame(df[c('uniqid', 'hh_id')]))$membership[df$uniqid]
df
  uniqid client_id hh_id group_id groups
1     u1        c1    h1        1      1
2     u1        c2    h1        1      1
3     u1        c3    h2        1      1
4     u2        c4    h1        1      1
5     u2        c5    h2        1      1
6     u3        c6    h3        2      2
7     u3        c7    h3        2      2
8     u3        c8    h4        2      2
```